# post a value of a form with hyperlink tag

Tags: php

The option choosen by the user from select box, it have to be send to the desired php file (getStatus.php) may be with get method or post method 
**but without using form submit button**

```
<select name="status">
  <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
  <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
  <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
</select>

<a href="getStatus.php"> Go </a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/r97e5ntt/3/

Answer (score 0):

You will have a var called `$_POST['status']` or `$_GET['status']` with the value equal to the value of the selected `option`. Without more code that's about all I can tell you.

EDIT: This will need to be made in a `form` with the `action` attribute set to `getStatus.php` and preferably a method of `POST`. There will not be any way around using a form if you want to pass data to another page unless you pass the data with AJAX. Why are forms not an option?

Answer (score 0):

use `javascript` for this :-

```
<select name="status" id="myselect">
  <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
  <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
  <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
</select>

<a href="#" onclick="click_me()"> Go </a>

<script>
function click_me(){
var selects = document.getElementById("myselect");
var selectedValue = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].value;// will gives u 2
var selectedText = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].text;// gives u value2

window.location = "getStatus.php?id="+selectedText;
}
</script>
```

Comment: select option doesn't change on getStatus.php page

Comment: <?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
?>
<select name="status" id="myselect">
  <option value="step_1" <?php if($_GET['id']=="step_1") echo'selected'; ?>>step_1</option>
  <option value="step_2" <?php if($_GET['id']=="step_2") echo'selected'; ?>>step_2</option>
  <option value="step_3" <?php if($_GET['id']=="step_3") echo'selected'; ?>>step_3</option>
</select>
<?php
}
?>

Comment: how can I do it with ajax with post method

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
  <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
  <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
</select>

<a href="#" onclick="getitem()"> Go </a>
<script>
function getitem(){
    var item = document.getElementById('status').value;
    location.href="getStatus.php?id="+item;

}
</script>
```